# Get class by name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two classes

```
class ClassOne
    def do_something
      [...]
    end
end

class ClassTwo
    def do_something
      [...]
    end
end
```

I am getting a class name (either ClassOne or ClassTwo) from the database and I want to call `do_something` in that class

so I have

```
class_name = "ClassOne"
```

and I want to call `ClassOne.do_something` or `ClassTwo.do_something` if class_name is equals to "ClassTwo".

I can't do it using a simple if condition, I have many classes and am checking if the class exists before calling..

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For vanilla ruby:

```
Kernel.const_get('ClassOne').do_something
```

For Rails:

```
'ClassOne'.constantize.do_something
```

Comment: I am getting an `undefined method 'do_something' for #<Class:0x9c9026c> (NoMethodError)` Any idea why?

Comment: You need to `def self.do_something` to use it as a class method.

Comment: Or leave the classes are they are and call `Kernel.const_get('ClassOne').new.do_something` / `'ClassOne'.constantize.new.do_something`

Answer (score 2):

Although you can convert any arbitrary string to a class using `constantize` from ActiveSupport if available, this could cause exceptions if users can submit the string in question. It might be safer to use a `case`:

```
case (with_class)
when 'ClassOne', 'ClassTwo'
  with_class.constantize.do_something
else
  raise "Um, what are you doing?"
end
```

The same thing could be achieved with a Hash or Array defining valid classes and testing with either `[]` or `include?` accordingly.

Comment: Let alone potential security issues as the user could discover all your class names or potential reveal the value of constants if they can generate the string.

Comment: The strings are not user generated. In the future I might be adding new classes and I don't want to update this part of the code every time a new class is available..

Comment: Remember you can pass around classes as variables within the same Ruby process, so there's no need to keep them as strings. It's fairly common to do things like `using_class = condition ? ClassA : ClassB` and then operate on that variable as if it was the class itself. Duck-typing makes this possible.

Answer (score -1):

`eval("#{classname}.do_something")`

Note: you have to change your code to `def self.do_something`, otherwise these are instance methods. It looks like this is your intention.

Comment: No, please, no. `eval` is not something you just whip out to do something like this. This is best reserved for situations where there is simply no other way.